# XAML vs XML in a UWP Application

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

Transitioning from WPF to UWP appears to be confusing. For example, trying to replace a regular XAML button with a standard Tile turns out not be a straight forward procedure since there is nothing like a Tile Control. Looking into [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-create-adaptive-tiles), I could see XML code vs XAML. It is not clear where the XML code fits into the presentation layer of an application. What does all this mean to developers that are transitioning from WPF to a UWP environment?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking (especially as XAML is a dialect of XML)

Comment: @RowlandShaw, true! But does this mean I could create a XAML file then add to it the XML code provided under "the adaptive tiles" documentation? I mean the main stream of WPF developers expect to work with XAML controls.

Comment: Adaptive tiles are completely different from a "Tile Control". The doc you linked to is how you can update the tile on the start screen. This is different from your application UI XAML

Answer (score 3):

XAML is the markup language for your UWP app UI, same concepts as in WPF.

For creating adaptive tiles on the start menu, this [XML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-tiles-schema) is provided for you. This is not XAML, so yes there is a new concept to learn.

If you prefer to use code to create the tiles, this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications/) will come in handy.

Also, you can use this [free app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/notifications-visualizer/9nblggh5xsl1?rtc=1) to design your adaptive tiles and interactive toasts more easily.